# Angular 5 response error in Nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, angular5, httpresponse

I am running an angular application **inside a docker container** which has nginx running inside it as a proxy server to serve the compiled angular files.

The HTTP requests that this angular app makes are all to a backend application running on another docker container through nginx on that container as well.

I am facing some strange issues which I did not see during development which has lead me to believe that these are nginx config issues.

Problem context:

- The angular app makes an HTTP Get call to the backend which returns an array of large JSON objects. Example: [ {json_obj1}, {json_obj2}, ...]
- At times I get two different errors when trying to retrieve these objects. ***These errors occur intermittently and alternates between these two for no apparent reason.***

  - Error 1: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` on the angular client
  - Error 2: `\api\objects\ [200]` `error: failed to load objects` (this is a custom error message that gets thrown when an incorrect response was received). **The strangest part is, the server returns a 200 response as indicated by the network status. But the observable still throws an error.** So what is happening is that nginx successfully receives the response but then when the UI tries to use it, it throws an error.

Example of this error: [image: Error2 error img]
- When the **number** of objects **returned** in this list is **small**, no issue occurs.

**Question**:

Is there an issue with nginx not being able to receive large responses? If so, shouldn't it tell me that? I have received an error before saying that the request I had sent was too large but never for the response.

Below is the angular application's docker container's nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 30m;

        #See http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-2-using-nginx-to-avoid-node-js-load
        proxy_cache_path        /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
        proxy_temp_path         /var/tmp;
        include                 mime.types;
        default_type            application/octet-stream;
        sendfile                on;
        keepalive_timeout       65;

        gzip                    on;
        gzip_comp_level         6;
        gzip_vary               on;
        gzip_min_length         1000;
        gzip_proxied            any;
        gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_buffers            16 8k;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html;
            expires -1;
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
         }
    }

}
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- I have tried adding a proxy_buffering and cache arguments to remove the use of the cache but this did not have any effect.